# Magento 2.3.4 - MySQL queries on url_rewrite operations has been improved

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.3.4

Recently I go through magento 2.3.4 Release Notes at: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/release-notes-2-3-4-open-source.html and I found:

> The performance of MySQL queries on url_rewrite operations has been improved. Previously, Magento ran a full scan of the table, and the query was very slow.

I am curious to know what they improve ? If we know, It will also help us to improve other table if required.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ask them what they had to do to avoid the full scan of the table.  It would be nice to know.

Comment: With this information, 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.